# Equivalent of "font-stretch" in Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

Does anyone knows what the equivalent of "font-stretch" in Tailwind CSS?
I have searched in the official documentation, but can't find anything related.

Here is an example: https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-css-font-stretch-property

I tried to

- Searched the official documentation of Tailwind CSS
- Did a google search, but it didn't helped
- Did a search in Stack Overflow, but no results

Comment: I think it's not included in the Tailwind utilities because it only works if the font you're using has the corresponding variations based on the width of characters.  Sadly, the browser doesn't actually stretch the font :-(

Comment: Thank you anyway ;)
Maybe @danila's reply is the best answer so far

Comment: Agreed!  If you have a font with variants, definitely add your own utility, or just wrap it in square brackets (`[font-stretch]`), which you can do with any [arbitrary css properties, values or variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-properties) in TailwindCSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an utility for that css property right now in Tailwind, but you can [add your own utilities](https://Sure,%20I%27m%20available%20all%20day%20before%2016:15), like that:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer utilities {
  .font-condensed {
    font-stretch: condensed;
  }
}
```

And use it as you normally do:

```
<span class="font-condensed">...
```